# R arrow package write_parquet VS write_dataset size

Tags: r, parquet, apache-arrow

I have a table of ~750Mb (5.5M lines) and want to create a file containing it that will be used when reading/writing. I used to use RDS files, but would like to move to parquet for cross-language support.

Creating a parquet file with `arrow::write_parquet()` results in a file of ~50Mb while creating a dataset with `arrow::write_dataset()` results in a file of ~600Mb.

I'm using the default compression "snappy" in bot cases.

Why is the dataset approach so much larger? I would expect a difference in size but not this much.

This is the code I used:

```
arrow::write_parquet(
  dta,
  file.path(outpath, "data.parquet"),
  compression = "snappy"
)

arrow::write_dataset(
  dta,
  file.path(outpath, "dataset"),
  hive_style = FALSE,
  compression = "snappy"
)
```

Comment: I tested with a 2.3Mi row frame, and the files are 205Mb and 255Mb, respectively, different but not nearly as different as in your example. My guess (and I really want somebody to provide canonical discussion here) is that the metadata indexing may be different when setting up for a `dataset`, since it can use partitioning, and perhaps does slightly-different optimizing of storage for multi-file reads? (Perhaps not.) I cannot find a difference in the apparent data, attributes, or read-times.

Comment: @r2evans Did you use any partitioning?

Comment: I did not, just a simple 1-file-save for both. But using `open_dataset` supports the notion of partitioning even if not specified.

Comment: Hi @JohnIoannides, can you update your question with more detail? Can you share something fully reproducible? If not, even just more of your code would help. My initial guess based on the file size differences is that data may be getting duplicated.

Comment: @amoeba I added the code I used. `dta` is a data.table with 15 columns and 5.5 milion lines. In the code I used no partitioning, but even with partitioning the size is similar.

Comment: Okay, that you're using data.table is a good lead. Are you able to reproduce this  with a base R data.frame or tibble? My guess is now that one code path serializes data.table metadata and the other doesn't.